# Searching and sorting on dynamic fields in ElasticSearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, search, aggregate, dynamic-mapping

Have created an object of colors, which contains the hex code of colors along with it's percentage,

***/colors/mapping*** returns

```
{   
  "colors": {
    "mappings": {
      "colors_array": {
        "dynamic": "strict",
        "properties": {
          "colors": {
            "dynamic": "true",
            "properties": {
              "#2f4f4f": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "#808080": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "#bc8f8f": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "#dc143c": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "#e6e6fa": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: Color hex codes are created as dynamic mapping objects

How exactly should I formulate the query such that I pass specific colors and the results are sorted on the basis of aggregated matching percentage i.e. sum the percentage of the colors that match and sort the results on the basis of this figure?

Comment: It isn't a good solution to use colors as keys, you can read about it more in ealstic blog (https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-crash-elasticsearch#mapping-explosion). So if yo will use solution from article, query will be so simple.

Comment: thanks, I was thinking about it as well, even though I have restricted the number of colors but still the number will be in hundred thousands. Reviewing the blog link